# With python mypy how can I pass a class into a generic and use it for deserializing?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

With python mypy how can I pass a class into a generic and use it for deserializing?

I have this class with a deserialize method

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class OpenApiResponse(typing.Generic[T]):
    response_cls: typing.Type[T]
    content: typing.Optional[typing.Dict[str, MediaType]] = None
    headers: typing.Optional[typing.Dict[str, typing.Type[HeaderParameterWithoutName]]] = None
    headers_schema: typing.Optional[typing.Type[schemas.DictSchema]] = None

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, response: urllib3.HTTPResponse, configuration: schema_configuration_.SchemaConfiguration) -> T:
        ...

        return cls.response_cls(
            response=response,
            headers=deserialized_headers,
            body=deserialized_body
        )
```

But mypy complains that:

```
Access to generic instance variables via class is ambiguous
```

on my return statement

My response_cls looks like this:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class ApiResponse(api_response.ApiResponse):
    response: urllib3.HTTPResponse
    body: application_json_schema.SchemaTuple
    headers: schemas.Unset = schemas.unset
```

Is there a better way to structure my code to do this deserialization?

- Should I make a `get_response_cls() -> T` method which returns T and must always be implemented in descendant classes?

I prefer all the data to be classvar data and to call the deserialize method.

An example class that uses this is:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class ApiResponse(api_response.ApiResponse):
    response: urllib3.HTTPResponse
    body: typing.Union[
        application_xml_schema.SchemaTuple,
        application_json_schema.SchemaTuple,
    ]
    headers: schemas.Unset = schemas.unset


class SuccessfulXmlAndJsonArrayOfPet(api_client.OpenApiResponse[ApiResponse]):
    response_cls = ApiResponse


    class ApplicationXmlMediaType(api_client.MediaType):
        schema: typing_extensions.TypeAlias = application_xml_schema.Schema


    class ApplicationJsonMediaType(api_client.MediaType):
        schema: typing_extensions.TypeAlias = application_json_schema.Schema
    Content = typing_extensions.TypedDict(
        'Content',
        {
            'application/xml': typing.Type[ApplicationXmlMediaType],
            'application/json': typing.Type[ApplicationJsonMediaType],
        }
    )
    content: Content = {
        'application/xml': ApplicationXmlMediaType,
        'application/json': ApplicationJsonMediaType,
    }
```

Comment: Could you please inform me of the preferred usage of your classes? Is the `JSONDetector` first-party or third-party?

Comment: JSONDetector does not matter i will remove it

Comment: The deserialize method is the method that is used by other code

Comment: well, for starters, `cls` won't have the attribute `response_cls` since you annotated it as an **instance variable**. Did you mean to annotate it as a class variable?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Class variables cannot use type vars.

Comment: @AlirezaRoshanzamir I've never thought about that but it makes sense, but in any case, it doesn't change the fact that `cls` won't have that attribute, certainly, not as the code is written, or as the annotations imply

Comment: Hmm yes I meant it to be a class variable

Comment: @spacether How would you like to populate the `OpenApiResponse` class? Do you want to instantiate it and then pass the instantiated variable to another method, or is there a specific approach you prefer?

Comment: @spacether it would help if you elaborated on how exactly you meant to use this class

Comment: I prefer all the data to be classvar data and to call the deserialize method.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're correct. The intended scope of the variables in the `OpenApiResponse` class and the reason for defining the `deserialize` method as a `classmethod` are unclear. So, I requested him to demonstrate the preferred usage of the class.

Comment: @spacether that doesn't really make much sense. Can you be more concrete?

Comment: I added the classes that use it to the problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by:

1. removing the @dataclasses.dataclass decorator from OpenApiResponse
2. or by creating a classmethod get_response method, which descendant classes must implement. Then call the get_response(response, headers, body) in deserialize to return the T output.

Here is the option 1 solution:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class ApiResponse:
    response: urllib3.HTTPResponse
    body: typing.Union[schemas.Unset, schemas.OUTPUT_BASE_TYPES] = schemas.unset
    headers: typing.Union[schemas.Unset, typing.Mapping[str, schemas.OUTPUT_BASE_TYPES]] = schemas.unset

T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound=ApiResponse)


class OpenApiResponse(typing.Generic[T]):
    response_cls: typing.Type[T]
    content: typing.Optional[typing.Dict[str, MediaType]] = None
    headers: typing.Optional[typing.Dict[str, typing.Type[HeaderParameterWithoutName]]] = None
    headers_schema: typing.Optional[typing.Type[schemas.DictSchema]] = None

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, response: urllib3.HTTPResponse, configuration: schema_configuration_.SchemaConfiguration) -> T:
        ...

        return cls.response_cls(
            response=response,
            headers=deserialized_headers,
            body=deserialized_body
        )
```

This works per mypy check:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class ApiResponse(api_response.ApiResponse):
    response: urllib3.HTTPResponse
    body: application_json_schema.api_response.ApiResponseDict
    headers: HeadersDict


class SuccessWithJsonApiResponse(api_client.OpenApiResponse[ApiResponse]):
    response_cls = ApiResponse


    class ApplicationJsonMediaType(api_client.MediaType):
        schema: typing_extensions.TypeAlias = application_json_schema.Schema
    content = {
        'application/json': ApplicationJsonMediaType,
    }
    headers=parameters
    headers_schema = Headers
import urllib3
response = urllib3.HTTPResponse()
from petstore_api.configurations import schema_configuration
configuration = schema_configuration.SchemaConfiguration()
reveal_type(SuccessWithJsonApiResponse.deserialize(response, configuration))
```

`revealed type is petstore_api.components.responses.response_success_with_json_api_response.ApiResponse`

Comment: Mypy does not deduce the type of `T` in the inherited class and considers it as `Any`. You can verify this by using the expression `reveal_type(FooOpenApiResponse.deserialize(..., ...))`.

Comment: I ran mypy on my file that includes SuccessfulXmlAndJsonArrayOfPet.deserialize() and it did not report errors and return types from deserialize are type hinted as method outputs. So it looks like it works as is.

Comment: Indeed, `Any` is compatible with all types. As an example, you can assign an `int` value to `response_cls` in the inherited class, and Mypy will not report any errors.

Comment: So Any is always cast to my ApiResponse by mypy under the hood? I will run reveal_type.

Comment: @spacether no, there is no casting, `Any` basically means "don't type check this", its purpose is to allow untyped code in an otherwise typed code-base. It is not allowed if you pass `--strict` to `mypy`

Comment: Just ran mypy and it does not see the type as Any, it sees it as T per the results I pasted from the mypy run

Comment: @spacether That's because you explicitly passed the `ApiResponse` to your base class type variable. It doesn't matter what your `response_cls` value is, as they can differ and Mypy doesn't check that. Simply pass a different value for `response_cls` and observe that Mypy won't check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to utilize the `OpenApiResponse` class through simple inheritance:

```
class FooOpenApiResponse(OpenApiResponse):
    response_cls = Foo
    content = ...
    headers = ...
    headers_schema = ...
```

Then the `OpenApiResponse` class should be defined as follows:

```
class OpenApiResponse:
    response_cls: typing.ClassVar[typing.Type[api_response.ApiResponse]]
    content: typing.ClassVar[typing.Optional[typing.Dict[str, MediaType]]]= None
    headers: typing.ClassVar[typing.Optional[typing.Dict[str, typing.Type[HeaderParameterWithoutName]]]] = None
    headers_schema: typing.ClassVar[typing.Optional[typing.Type[schemas.DictSchema]]] = None

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, response: urllib3.HTTPResponse, configuration: schema_configuration_.SchemaConfiguration) -> api_response.ApiResponse:
        ...

        return cls.response_cls(
            response=response,
            headers=deserialized_headers,
            body=deserialized_body
        )
```

Please note that I utilized [ClassVar](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html?highlight=classvar#class-attribute-annotations) to highlight that the variables are defined in the class scope rather than the instance. Additionally, I used `api_response.ApiResponse` instead of `T` because [`ClassVar`s cannot utilize `Type` of `TypeVar`s](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5144).

**Additional note:**
According to `PEP 484`, generic metaclasses are not supported, meaning it is not possible to create a generic metaclass to enhance the type safety of the return value in the `deserialize` method of the inherited class.

Comment: But this is not a metaclass, right? And I can bind T to to ApiResponse? They can utilize the type if you do not define them as classvars.

Comment: No, as I mentioned before and provided the corresponding GitHub issue link, you cannot utilize `ClassVar[Type[T]]`. If you attempt to deceive Mypy by substituting `Type[T]` for `ClassVar[Type[T]]`, it will not aid in typing and will evaluate `T` as `Any`. You can test this to verify.

Comment: Does your solution allow other classes to be used in place of OpenApiResponse.response_cls that inherit from api_rresponse.ApiResonse?

Comment: @spacether Yes, actually, I tested my solution. The only weakness is that the `deserialize` return type is `api_response.ApiResponse` and is not specialized based on the `response_cls` type. But overall, it's better than the generic `Any` type.